# Google App Script Setting Down a background from drive into a web app

Tags: javascript, html, css

currently trying to import an image into a web app to set it as a background for a web app created in app scripts, but I do not have a clear understanding of how to import it or how to define the background css. Is this possible to perform?

```js
function doGet(e){
    var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("CreditForm");
    tmp.pic = DriveApp.getFilesByName("congruent_pentagon.png");
  
    return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: pic;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not publicly available, one option may be to upload it into Google Drive (you may also then need to make it publicly accessible). In your image tag, specify the source per its URL:

```
<img src="image_url">
```